# Eclipse - How to format selected code from multiple lines to a single line?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, if I select some code which is split on more than one line and I want to format it on one line only, how can I do that?

I want to know if it's possible to configure the js formatter inside eclipse so to be able to use just SHIFT + CMD + F.

Code split on several lines:

```
$('a#pop1').fancybox({
     'padding': 0,
     'margin-left': 30,
     'width': 728,
     'height': 400,
     'maxWidth': 728,
     'maxHeight': 400
 });
```

and how I would like to achieve, split on a single line.

```
$('a#pop1').fancybox({'padding': 0,'margin-left': 30,'width': 728,'height': 400,'maxWidth': 728,'maxHeight': 400});
```

Comment: http://javascriptcompressor.com/ and http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: No, I just need to know if it's possible within the Eclipse IDE. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do couple of thing to prevent code formatting.
Follow below step :

1. Right click on project and open properties.
2. Go to `Preferences > JavaScript > Code Style > Formatter`
3. Check `Enable Project Specific settings`.
4. Click on `Edit` button. Change Profile Name on top of dialog.
5. Go to `New Line` tab. Un-Checked option under `Object initializers` section.
6. Now go to `Line Wrapping` tab. increase `Maximum line width` parameter value.
7. Click on `Ok` than `Applly` than `Ok`.

This will now prevent your JavaScript code to format like above.

After that select your code and press `Ctrl + Shift + f` key combination to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can be helpful for you: [Using the code formatter - Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_codeformatter.htm)

Or this one, maybe, that has got some instructions: [Formatting Your Code Using the Eclipse Code Formatter](http://www.peterfriese.de/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/)

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
Preferences > JavaScript > Code Style > Formatter
```

These are the steps:

Create a new profile (since you cannot edit the builted-in one), if you haven't already, and click Edit....

Open the Line Wrapping tab.

in it edit settings for your function

Click Apply, and Ok.